# Visual Studio model link not working correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, modeling

First, let me explain what I have done:

I have installed the Visual Studio 2010 Feature Pack both on my local computer and on the TFS host.

[The process is documented by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657802.aspx)

1. I have a VS 2010 modeling solution with a component diagram.
2. I have created a work item of type Model (custom work item type).
3. I have created an association from a component in the component diagram, to the Model WI (using Link to Work Item)
4. The component diagram correctly links to the Model WI
5. The Model WI correctly contains a model link to the component in the component diagram

Problem: When I click the model link in the Model WI 'All links' tab, I get the following error:

> Cannot find the linked model element. The corresponding diagram file or modeling project might have been renamed, moved, or deleted. To fix the link, click the Edit Link button in this work item to re-link the element

I tried to do exactly this, by re-selecting the component using the 'Select model element' dialog. The error is not resolved.

I tried to delete the link and re-create it by creating a new model link. The error is not resolved.

The link looks like this:

> ModelLink: modelbus://ComponentDesignerAdapter.1.0/SystemComponentOverview/Architecture::ComponentName/$source control location/filename%comonent-guid

This works perfectly for another modeling project. The error only occurs in this specific modeling project, however it affects more than one component (I do not know if it affects all components in this project)

So my question is this. What could possibly cause this error?

Update: We just realized the error only occurs on my computer. When my colleague attempts to follow the link, the diagram opens correctly. I have tried 'Get latest version' from source control and restarting Visual Studio. Nothing has resolved the issue.

Update 2: I tried creating a new workspace, to no avail. At this point I am concidering re-installing Visual Studio, but I'll hold it off a day or so in case someone knows what might be causing this.